# How to link a 3ds max scene with my directx 9 game?

Tags: directx-9, 3dsmax

I have purchased the book programming a multiplayer fps book.
The problem is that I am not able to get the 3d's max scene to load. Is there a step to load a library of 3d's max to load the scene? What is the missing piece in loading the scene. I am not able to load the scene.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load and render 3D mesh data, you need some kind of exporter to convert the 3D Studio MAX authoring data into a binary form suitable for rendering, and some sort of rendering engine capable of drawing that binary form.

For exporting the data, you can use an existing tool such as [Open-Asset-Importer-Lib](http://assimp.org/) or write your own using something like [Autodesk FBX](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fbx/overview).

There are of course numerous choices for rendering engines, or you can write your own from scratch.

> Note that Direct3D 9 is extremely old at this point. DirectX 11 is the modern sweet spot for starting out programming Direct3D. See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and [DirectX SDK Samples Content Exporter](https://github.com/walbourn/contentexporter).

Comment: How to load a 3d's max scene in DirectX 11?

Comment: As I said, you don't. You export a 3D MAX scene, and then render it using DirectX 11. There's no 'magic' way to do this. You might want to take a look at Unity and/or Unreal Engine.

Comment: I am not able to get the scene to load in my game. For some reason it is not locating the m_firstFrame in my application. What could be the possible reasons for not loading the scene?

Answer (score 0):

The 3dsmax file format is propriatary. You just don't load those *.max files into anything but 3ds max. Like Chuck said above, you have to export your max file from 3ds max into a common, 3rd party file format like OBJ, FBX, etc...
There is probably a hundred 3D third-party file formats out there. We have no idea which 'game' you are trying to code up, and you have not provided any information, except asked all the wrong questions.
DirectX 11 is a graphics platform provided by microsoft. it is file format agnostic. It is up to you to learn it.